# "keyerror" when trying to access a node attribute in networkx

Tags: python, twitter, networkx, graph-theory

I have a network of twitter followers. each follower has multiple attributes like follower count, username, location etc. i am trying to find the follower counts for all of the predecessor nodes in the graph. I can do this using the `predecessor` function in networokx, but when I try to access the node attribute i get a "key error" on follower count.
heres my code

```
   if len(list(DG.predecessors(node))) > 0: #only loop through nodes that have 1 or more predecsoor
       for pred_node in DG.predecessors(node):
       a = DG.nodes[pred_node]['follower_count'] # Key value error here
```

The error occurs when when i try to assign it to a

Can this be down to how I've set up the attributes? for reference see the code below for how I set the attributes

```
import csv
import networkx as nx


with open('twitter_nodelist.csv', 'r') as nodecsv: # Open the file
    nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv) # Read the csv
   
    nodes = [n for n in nodereader][1:]

node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes] # Get a list of only the node names

with open('twitter_edgelist.csv', 'r') as edgecsv: # Open the file
    edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv) # Read the csv
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader][1:] # Retrieve the data
    
print(len(node_names))

print(len(edges))



DG = nx.Graph()

DG.add_nodes_from(node_names)
DG.add_edges_from(edges)

total_nodes = DG.number_of_nodes()

print(nx.info(DG))

print(total_nodes)


username_dict = {}
user_screen_name_dict = {}
tweetid_dict = {}
tweet_text_dict = {}
user_followers_count_dict = {}
user_friends_count_dict = {}
user_location_dict = {}
user_url_dict = {}
tweet_created_at_dict = {}
tweet_source_dict = {}




for node in nodes: # Loop through the list, one row at a time
    username_dict[node[0]] = node[1]
    user_screen_name_dict[node[0]] = node[2]
    tweet_text_dict[node[0]] = node[3]
    user_followers_count_dict[node[0]] = node[4]
    user_friends_count_dict[node[0]] = node[5]
    user_location_dict = node[6]
    user_url_dict = node[7]
    tweet_created_at_dict = node[8]
    tweet_source_dict = node[9]



nx.set_node_attributes(G, username_dict, 'username')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, user_screen_name_dict, 'screen_name')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, tweet_text_dict, 'tweet_text')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, user_followers_count_dict, 'follower_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, user_friends_count_dict, 'friend_count')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, user_location_dict, 'location')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, user_url_dict, 'URL')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, tweet_created_at_dict, 'tweet_creation_time')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, tweet_source_dict, 'tweet_source')
```

I have tried printing the dictionaries and they print without issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Turns out I hadn't set the node attributes properly. I Used G rather than DG